# Using multiple class in image_tag helper in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

How do I pass multiple classes to the `image_tag` helper in a Rails 5 app? I want to convert this HTML `<img>` tag:

```
<img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="images/m1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```

into

```
<%= image_tag @post.picture.url if @post.picture? %>
```

with the Rails `image_tag` helper. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your `img` in the example isn't a valid one, you can try with:

```
<% if @post.picture %> # To check if @post.picture isn't nil
  <%= image_tag @post.picture.url, class: 'etalage_thumb_image img-responsive' %>
<% end %>
```

Multiple classes separated by a white space.

Comment: Multiple classes are separated by a space, not a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is **invalid** to begin with. It should be:

```
<img class="etalage_thumb_image img-responsive" src="images/m1.jpg" />
```

...otherwise the second `class` attribute overrides the first one.

**Possible solution:**

```
<% if @post.picture %>
  <%= image_tag @post.picture.url, class: "etalage_thumb_image img-responsive" %>
<% end %>
```